# How to Delete Item from Graphics scene from Main Window Tool Box?

Tags: qt, signals-slots, qgraphicsview

In Graphic View set the scene, In Graphic scene(subclass od QGraphicscene) class added Delete item slot.In scene class by delete key i able to delete item but when i call from main window it wont delete item . i am getting call in Delete item slot but selectedItems  = 0. what may be causing problem?
**In Graphic scene class**

```
    void GraphicScene::DeleteItems()//Delete Item slot in scene class
    {
       qDebug()<<"delete items"<< selectedItems().count();
       foreach(QGraphicsItem* item, selectedItems())
       {
            removeItem(item);
            delete item;
       }
    }

    void GraphicScene::keyReleaseEvent(QKeyEvent * keyEvent)// Delete key works fine
    {

         if (selectedItems().isEmpty())
              return;
         if(keyEvent->key() == Qt::Key_Delete)
         {
            DeleteItems();
         }
   }
```

**In MainWindow class**

```
    MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) 
    {
      addToolBar(Qt::TopToolBarArea, mpEditToolbar = new 
                     QToolBar());
      DeleteAction = new QAction(QIcon(":/images/delete.png"),tr("Object 
                                       &Delete"), this);
      DeleteAction->setStatusTip(tr("Delete item"));
      connect(DeleteAction,SIGNAL(triggered()),mpGraphView  , 
              SIGNAL(DeleteObject())); // grpah view connecting to delete slot
      mpEditToolbar->addAction(DeleteAction);
    }
```

When i do from delete key works fine its not working with tool box delete action. what is the problem?

Comment: `SIGNALs` are connected to `SLOTs`, not `SIGNALs` - as it is in your `connect` function

Comment: @pau True..  i am connecting to slot in other construcor(mpGraphView)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Main Window class  have private members of GraphicsView and GraphicScene class(subclass)
so that it will be easy to call slot.

```
  class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
  {
    Q_OBJECT

    public:
        explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
        ~MainWindow();

    private:
        GraphFrame              *mpGraphFrame;
        GraphicScene            *mpScene;
   }
```

**MainWindow.cpp**
Connect should be in where you creating GraphicScene Object

```
 MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) 
 {
  addToolBar(Qt::TopToolBarArea, mpEditToolbar = new 
                 QToolBar());
  DeleteAction = new QAction(QIcon(":/images/delete.png"),tr("Object 
                                   &Delete"), this);
  DeleteAction->setStatusTip(tr("Delete item"));
  connect(DeleteAction,SIGNAL(triggered()),mpGraphScene  , 
          DeleteItems(); 
  mpEditToolbar->addAction(DeleteAction);
 }
```